# MAC: NPM installs modules globally but commands can't be found

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, taco

Complete MAC noob here but I've been building an iOS version of my app using MacInCloud where I start a Remotebuild from terminal on to the MacInCloud, push to the MacInCloud from Visual Studio on my Windows machine, then open the xcode project on the MacInCloud and finish up the publishing process.  So I finally broke down and bought my own Mac and I'm struggling to replace the MacInCloud with my local Mac.

The problem I'm having is I set up my Mac, installed Nodejs (with npm obviously) and then ran:

`sudo npm install -g remotebuild`

I originally ran without sudo but got the EACCES permission denied error so added sudo.  Then ran:

`remotebuild`

Which gave me

> "remotebuild: command not found"

So I verified node:

`node -v`

> v8.11.2

I verified npm:

`npm -v`

> 5.6.0

I went to the /.npm-global/lib/node_modules folder and I can literally see the remotebuild folder and files.  I've also tried opening a terminal from the bin folder under remotebuild (where the remotebuild executable actually is) and I still get a command not found error.

So then I tested something I'm a little more comfortable with: angular cli.  That didn't work either

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

`ng -v`

> "ng: Command not found"

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Node, I've run the install for remotebuild, I've tried nvm, I'm honestly out of ideas.

Thoughts?

Comment: How have you installed node, and is the global bin folder in your PATH?

Comment: I installed node via the pkg file downloaded from nodejs.org. I also ran export path for the remote build folder, should I run it for the main .npm-global folder? I will try that real quick.

Comment: whats the output of `npm bin -g`

Comment: /Users/me/.npm-global/bin

Comment: FINALLY!!!! That was it, just had to export that path and now remote build command works! Thanks so much! Will you post that as an answer and then I'll mark it as the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to ensure that `npm`s global `bin` folder is added to your `PATH`. How you do this may depend on your shell. However you can execute `npm bin -g` to get the global `bin` folder of `npm`.